# LOGIC: The edges of a n-corner base pyramid are colored in red or blue, is there any for point fo which 3 edges of the same color are connected

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

My professor gave this to me,I AM THINKING ABOUT IT FOR a day but don’t find a 100 % proof.

the base of a pyramid is a regular n-corner.  every connection between two corners of the pyramid, with the exception of the sides of the base, is colored either red or blue.

PROOF: For n = 20 there are three corners of the pyramid for every such coloration, which are connected by three segments of the same color.

Comment: This is a problem posed by the german nationwide contest Bundeswettbewerb Mathematik, www.bundeswettbewerb-mathematik.de ,
solutions to be found im homework and turned in by march 3rd 2021.
It seems that johnboehmer - whatever his/her real name is - posted this in violation of the rules.
I kindly ask everybody not to participate in any discussion with regard to this problem before march 3rd. Thank you very much. Karl Fegert
Head of grading department BWM